# The TransitionCompletedEvent is not being raised

Tags: vb.net, dll, event-handling, transition

I'm using this library for transitions: https://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/

I'm trying to handle this event: https://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/wiki/CodingWithTransitions#Using_the_TransitionCompletedEvent

it says its raised by the background transition thread when the transition is conpleted. it isnt being raised though. Also, how do you specify which transition you want to raise the event?

I'm trying to code it in VB but its not working. Can anyone give me an example of how its done?

This is the relevant bit:

*Transitions are run asynchronously. If you need to know when a transition has completed you can register with the TransitionCompletedEvent. This is raised from the Transition's background thread when the transition is completed. If your event-handler is on a UI object such as a form, the event will automatically be marshaled to the UI thread.*

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ClosingTranstitions()
    Opacity = 1

    Dim tr_form = New Transition(New TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(200))
    tr_form.add(Me, "Opacity", 0.0)

    Dim tr_Title = New Transition(New TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(200))
    tr_Title.add(Title, "Left", 0)

    Dim tr_Content = New Transition(New TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(300))
    tr_Content.add(Content, "Left", -10)

    tr_Title.run()
    tr_form.run()
    tr_Content.run()

End Sub

Public Event TransitionCompletedEvent As EventHandler(Of Transition.Args) 'This event is raised when transitions are complete

Private Sub theHandlerFunction(sender As Object, args As Transition.Args) Handles Me.TransitionCompletedEvent
    MsgBox("Closing")
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Anyone??

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: @BrantOlsen I added my code to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transition handler to trigger, you must add an event handler :

```
AddHandler tr_form. TransitionCompletedEvent, AddressOf theHandlerFunction
```

In fact you will also have to store tr_form, so later you can remove this handler when creating a new transition, otherwise you'll have memory leaks UNLESS you restart again and again the same transition that you create/hook only once.